# Why does my program crash after entering an integer? - C

Tags: c

I'm extremely new to C coding and i'm wondering why this is crashing like this? After I input a value and press enter, my program instantly crashes. I remember learning there are times when you use a & with an array in the scanf line and sometimes you don't. So when I remove the & it crashes instantly. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this problem and would appreciate help.

What i'm trying to accomplish:

- "Write a program that asks the user to enter a sequence of integers terminated by 0 ( the last number is 0)  and prints all the numbers entered on one line."
- The program crashes before I can enter the other variables. I was not done coding but since it keeps crashing instantly I can't go further.

  ```
   int main () {
         int ru[1000];
         int read;
         int nums;
         int counts;

         printf("Enter integers, press 0 to end user input \n");

         while (nums>0) {
             scanf("%d",&ru[nums]);

             if (nums==0)
                 printf("%d ", ru[nums]);
         }

        system("pause>nul");
        return 0;
   }
  ```

Comment: `nums` is uninitialized.

Comment: `while (nums>0) `.. `nums` contains garbage value.

Comment: If you do not explicitly initialize automatic local variables, like `num`, you may not use them in comparisons, otherwise you'd invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, the real crash here is from accessing `&ru[nums]`

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: Something is not initialized, so how would one fix it? Hm.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by several people already, you don't ever assign a value to `nums` at any point in your code, but make use of it in several places.

You should populate `nums` and whilst it's more than zero (this should probably be not equal to zero if you want to also include negative integers), store it's value into your array. You can track where you are in the array using another variable (I've picked the `read` one that you'd already declared), making sure that it is first initialised to 0.

Once the `while` loop is terminated, either by `nums` being zero or you filling up the array, you can then print out the numbers you've collected.

```
int main (void) {
   int ru[1000];
   int read=0;
   int nums;
   int counts;

   printf("Enter integers, press 0 to end user input \n");

   scanf("%d",&nums);
   while ((nums>0)&&(read<1000)) {
       ru[read++]=nums;
       scanf("%d",&nums);
   }
   for(counts=0;counts<read;counts++) {
       printf("%d ",ru[counts]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   system("pause>nul");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scanf() you are using as the following prototype:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

you should give the de pointer to the buffer variable as a parameter but your are giving a pointer to an array (pointer to a pointer).:

```
scanf("%d",&ru[nums]);
```

A solution to your problem might be:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main () 
 {
        int ru[1000];
        int i = 0;
        printf("Enter integers, press 0 to end user input \n");
        do
        {
            scanf("%d",&ru[i]);
        }while (ru[i]!= 0 && i++ < 1000);
        for(i = 0; ru[i] != 0 ; i++)
            printf("%d ", ru[i]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```